# Give conditions on a,b,c, and d such that A has two, one, and no eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I am given that matrix 
$$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and I need to find conditions on a,b,c, and d such that A has

1. Two distinct real eigenvalues
2. One real eigenvalue
3. No real eigenvalue

I was trying to think this through and all I can figure out is that would it have two distinct eigenvalues if det(A-$\lambda$I)=0?

Comment: **Hint:** For a $2 \times 2$ matrix, $\det(A - \lambda I) = \lambda^2 - (\operatorname{tr}A)\lambda + (\det A)$.  How do you make a quadratic polynomial have two, one, or zero real roots?

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ real or can they be complex?

Comment: @copper.hat It does not specify

Comment: Compute the polynomial $x \mapsto \det(xI-A)$ and solve for the roots (which are the eigenvalues). Then you have a bit of work to determine conditions so 1-3 above are satisfied.

Comment: I've actually done all that for another problem. So, I have all that. I was suppose to prove the det(a-$\lambda$I)= $\lambda^2$-(tr(a))$\lambda$ + detA and I've solved the quadratic equation for $\lambda$... I sadly still don't know where to go from here

Comment: Well, it is a little cumbersome if $a-d$ are allowed to be complex. You might start with real values, that is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Okay so could I say i have no solutions if 1/2(a+d) = $sqrt{(a-d)^2 - 4bc}$ and 1/2(a+d) = -$sqrt{(a-d)^2 - 4bc}$

Comment: Hint: use the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$det(A-\lambda I)=0$$
$$(a-\lambda)(d-\lambda)-bc=0$$
$$ad-a\lambda-d\lambda +\lambda² -bc=0  $$
$$\lambda² -(a+d)\lambda+(ad-bc)=0  $$
Making analysis under discriminant and you will see...

$(a+d)²-4(ad-bc)>0$ it is $\Delta >0 <=>$ $2$ real eigenvalues

$(a+d)²-4(ad-bc)=0$ it is $\Delta =0 <=>$ $1$ real eigenvalues

$(a+d)²-4(ad-bc)<0$ it is $\Delta <0 <=>$ $0$ real eigenvalues

Well, all this is because $R$ is incomplete field, in case you have Complex matrices you lost the characteristic of order set, but you have that all polynomials have that same number of roots that their's  degree, then you have one(multiplicity 2) or two eigenvalues.

Comment: Yeah but you do not prove the converse (<=). But you can change your => to <=>! BTW, `\Longrightarrow` yields $\Longrightarrow$ and `\Longleftrightarrow` yields $\Longleftrightarrow$.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems you did compute the characteristic polynomial $X^2-(a+d)X+ad-bc$ and its discriminant, though it seems you used an incorrect formula for the latter. The correctly computed discriminant is $(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)=a^2+d^2-2ad+bc$ which is also $(a-d)^2+4bc$. Supposing the entries $a,b,c,d$ are themselves real, you will be in cases 1, 2, 3 according as this discriminant is positive, zero, or negative. (In case of complex entries $a,b,c,d$, it is unlikely there are any real eigenvalues at all, but the precise conditions become rather complicated to state; notably "one real eigenvalue" could either be a double root, or be paired with another non-real complex root.)